# setting up dimens Nexus 5

Tags: android, android-resolution

my project currently just has one dimens file.. I know all my dimens look good on a nexus 5 which i believe has a dpi of 445 and a dpx of 3.  My question is does that make it mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi?  I am asking as i want to use this as the standard when i go ahead and make my other dimens files.

according to this graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NXYH.png
that would make it xxhdpi which seems wrong to me, especially since our dimens seem really small on a tab 4 which has a much bigger screen than the nexus 5.

Comment: We have one dimens for phones and one for tablet and it really work out quite well. We usually just setup our dimens on an mdpi device and usually if it looks good on mdpi it looks good on the rest.

Answer (score 2):

A set of six generalized densities:
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

Since Nexus 5 has pixel density of 445 therefore it is xxhdpi

Read this android developer [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Also have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android?lq=1)

Comment: Nexus 5 is indeed xxhdpi